# weak formulation of the p-Laplacian.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can it be claimed that $\int_{\Omega}\Delta_p u |\phi|^{p-2}\phi dx=\int_{\Omega}\Delta_p \phi|u|^{p-2}udx$ is the generalization of $\int_{\Omega}\Delta u \phi dx=\int_{\Omega}\Delta\phi udx$ over $C_0^2(\overline{\Omega})$?. Here $\Delta_p$, $\Delta$ are the $p$-Laplacian and the Laplacian operators respectively.

Answer (score 2):

By partial integration, one finds
$$
\int_\Omega (\Delta_p u) |\phi|^{p-2}\phi \ dx \\
= -\int_\Omega |u|^{p-2} \nabla u \cdot \nabla(|\phi|^{p-2}\phi) dx\\
= -(p-1)\int_\Omega |u|^{p-2} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi \cdot |\phi|^{p-2} dx.
$$
Now the right-hand side is symmetric with respecto to $u$ and $\phi$, so the claimed identity holds.

Comment: The $p$-Laplacian is not linear.

Comment: @Daw...$\Delta_p u=\nabla.(|u|^{p-2}\nabla u)$ is a nonlinear operator.

Comment: @Florian I must have missed the subscipt $p$, see the edit.

Comment: @ Daw...Sorry for the above definition. The correct one is $\Delta_p u=\nabla.(|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u)$. Hence this should be $\int_{\Omega}(\Delta_p u)|\phi|^{p-2}\phi=-\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u.\nabla(|\phi|^{p-2}\phi)$ in which case the symmetry breaks!